# Saas cannot find stylesheet to import. Django project

Tags: django, sass

I am trying to use bootstrap saas in my django project.

I installed saas and bootstrap via npm sucessfully however when I try to compile my sass/scass to css I get an error below. I think i am somehow getting file directories incorrect

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywh5M.jpg) Static folder has my main.scss and main.css files

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icCum.jpg)

Comment: Please add the code directly to your question and do not use screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

The `node_modules/` directory is not a child directory of your `static/` directory, where the sass file is located, you are trying to convert. The import path in your sass file is relative to the directory it is stored and not relative to the directory you are calling `sass` from.

Comment: It is now working, I didn't install node_modules in the directory which was supposed to be. Thank you for pointing that out